# How can I call different Ionic toast after I call a service?

Tags: angular, ionic3, android-toast

for some reason i have a problem to call a ionic toast just after have a response from a service in angular controller.

based on a precise string in response i have to initialize different messages.
I have already check for the correct response from service (is working as i expected).

here what i have done:

```
showToast(position: string, message: string) {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: message,
    duration: 2000,
    position: position
  });
  toast.present(toast);
}

logForm() {
  console.log(this.userRegister.value);
  this.utente = this.userRegister.value;
  this.UtentiService.addUser(this.utente);

  //controllo se l'utente esiste già
  this.UtentiService.getSingleUser(this.utente).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.risposta = JSON.stringify(data.messaggio);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      alert(this.risposta);
      if (this.risposta === "ko_singoloFound") {
        this.showToast('bottom', 'Ti sei registrato con successo!');
      }
      if (this.risposta === "ok_singoloFound") {
        this.showToast('middle', 'Utente già registrato!');
      }
    });
}
```

apparently seems like the function wont in the if statements inside the last callback.

What i am doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: Are you showing two toast at the same time ?

Comment: no only one but initialize it in different way (based on 2 parameter):
showToast(position: string, message:string)

Comment: this condition is the same `this.risposta === "ko_singoloFound"` in the if conditions so you are executing both, you are creating 2 toast at the same time

Comment: @SergioEscudero they are "ok_singoloFound" and "ko_singoloFound", they are similiar but not identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was in JSON.stringify(data.messaggio); the the answer was already a string and returned to me ""ko_singoloFound"" ko_singoloFound.